# Access path of audio files stored in native ipod application of iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have built an iPhone application whereby I want to upload video, images and audio stored in user's iPhone to a server. I have successfully done this for video and images stored in photo library. The code for this is as follows:

```
      imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, 90);

      NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

       if (image_selected)  {
                stringForImagePathToUpload = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"..."];
                [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringForImagePathToUpload]];
            }else if (video_selected){
                stringForVideoPathToUpload = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"..."];
                [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringForVideoPathToUpload]];
            }

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"*****"]; 

        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];  

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];       

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        if (image_selected) {
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"%@"".jpg""\r\n\r\n", imageTitle.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        }else if (video_selected){

            NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromURL:videoURL error:nil];
            NSData *data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"%@"".m4v""\r\n\r\n", imageTitle.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
        }

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    /* setting the body of the post to the reqeust */

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    /* setting up the connection to the web*/
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];



    NSString *returnString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];

    NSLog(@"Content uploaded %@", returnString);
```

Now, I found ot the audio files get stored in the ipod application of the iPhone. I want to know if I can access the path to this audio like i did for images and videos from photo library. If it is possible to access the audio files, please help me to know how to access them.